# É possível o htaccess interpretar um arquivo como diretório (subdomínio)?

Tags: htaccess

Tenho vários arquivos com diversos conteúdos, tipo: ajuda.php?go=faq, ajuda.php?go=form, etc. Queria algo como: ajuda.site.com/faq, ajuda.site.com/form, etc. Seria possível via htaccess que o arquivo ajuda.php seja interpretado como diretório?

Comment: @Bacco é que na hora de criar um subdomínio o servidor entende como pasta, por isso.

Comment: Mais fácil você explicar o que quer que aconteça. Não consegui ver a relação desse seu último comentário com a pergunta. O que quer fazer exatamente? Subdomínio não tem nada a ver nem com PHP nem com .htaccess diretamente.

Comment: @Bacco veja bem. Esqueçamos php e focamos apenas htaccess. Já tenho muita coisa feita (códigos) e queria aproveitar, tipo: se ao invés de ser exibido na barra do navegador site.com/ajuda?go=faq, etc. fosse ajuda.site.com/faq. Sei que isso é possível se fizesse o diretorio "ajuda" e eu apontasse o subdomínio para lá, mas queria isso diretamente no arquivo já pronto.

Comment: @Junior, não há resposta mais clara que a a minha.

Comment: Veja aqui, provavelmente já temos resposta no site, o que você procura é URL amigável: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=URL+amigavel+htaccess

Comment: Sò pra comentar se alguém mais precisar desse tipo de solução, mais simples que isso tudo é configurar o servidor pra tratar arquivos sem extensão como PHP, assim já resolve sem .htaccess - Pode ser inviável numa aplicação muito complexa que já esteja pronta, mas pra começar do zero, pode ser uma boa, desde que a pessoa tenha controle sobre a hospedagem.

Answer (score 0):

As suas tags de link e a forma com que você abrirá os seus conteúdos, você mesmo terá que alterar. Então onde você usava:

```
ajuda.php?go=faq
```

Agora passará a escrever:

```
ajuda.php/faq
```

É necessário que as suas regras traduzam o amigável para a querystring.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ ajuda.php?go=$1 [NC,L]
```

> > [É muito simples fazer isso. Recomendo uma leitura aqui.](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html)

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, também não sei o motivo, mas suponho que isto `ajuda.php/faq` esteja errado, conforme o seu `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$` o acesso deveria ser `http://site/faq/` apenas, não?

Comment: O cara quer trocar pelo subdomínio, o que requeriria mais do que o HTACESS, seria necessário uma configuração de DNS que o Index deste subdominio apontasse para a pesquisa!